# how to make the image phash value just 16bit

Tags: c#, image, phash

I used https://github.com/pgrho/phash in c#. I want to get hash value like `51A70C737AD03A97` (16bit);

But it make phash value like : `7CFF35758E9E42009DA0839E955B465588816A709063336E8F81639A965D6381A784738995686189`(80bit).

I use the code:

```
            var bitmap = (Bitmap)img;
            var hash = ImagePhash.ComputeDigest(bitmap.ToLuminanceImage());
            byte[] bytearr = hash.Coefficients;
            return byteToHexStr(bytearr);
```

Now, who knows how to make a hash value just 16bit, like `51A70C737AD03A97`;

Comment: How did you get 51A70C737AD03A97?

Comment: These aren't 16bits and 80bits, but 16bytes (= 128bits) and 80bytes (=640bits).

Comment: @ John_ReinstateMonica that make by javascript , I need make the same in c#.

Comment: @ ckuri ye, can you know how to make 128bits value?